# Plot doesn't continue after killing Darko

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

After finishing [That Special Someone](http://gta.wikia.com/That_Special_Someone) by killing Darko, I didn't receive a call by Pegorino, as the wiki says I should. But this means that I can't continue to the following story missions.

I did a few optional missions after that, so I don't think waiting will help.

Am I missing something or is this a bug? Is there some way of fixing this apart from loading an old save?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, I looked wrong. I had to do [Diamonds Are a Girl's Best Friend](http://gta.wikia.com/Diamonds_Are_a_Girl%27s_Best_Friend) before getting to [One Last Thing](http://gta.wikia.com/One_Last_Thing).